# xmllint warns about missing space of xslt generated file

Tags: xml, xslt, xmllint, libxslt

When running xmllint on a xml file generated by xsltproc, I get the following error:

```
xmllint --valid --noout build/docbook/index.xml                                                         :(
build/docbook/index.xml:1: parser error : Space needed here
<?xml version="1.0"?>
                   ^
```

Is this space really necessary? Is this an issue of xsltproc?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the snippet. Consider to post a minimal but complete `index.xml` document that allows us to reproduce the problem. What happens if you load `index.xml` in a browsers like Firefox or Chrome? Do they show any parse errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a space there. Xmllint probably wants you to put the encoding attribute next which would be separated by a space, which would be good form, but also not strictly necessary.